# Is calling an API endpoint to update a piece of data in the BE from a useEffect considered to be a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` in my page component that is responsible for calling an `updateViewCount` to my backend.

Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  backend.updateViewCount(pageId);
},[pageId])
```

This is a NextJS app and I statically generate my pages. That's why the only place I can do this is from the client code, with a `useEffect`.

React strict mode is calling that effect twice in my dev environment.

I know that this is not going to impact my production build, but it's supposed to catch bad practices in dev mode.

Is calling an API endpoint that mutates a piece of data from a `useEffect` considered to be a bad practice?

If I don't want it to call my endpoint twice in dev mode, do I have any other option other than disabling strict mode?

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

[image]

Comment: What are the values for `pageId` that cause the useEffect to run? It would only call if the component were mounted, unmounted, and then mounted again (or if the value for `pageId` has changed). Having an API call inside a `useEffect` is a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: `pageId` is just `string` and only changes if you render a different page, which should indeed retrigger the `effect`. I agree is a valid thing to do. Why do they bother to call it twice in `dev` mode then? From the docs, it looks like they are trying to uncover bad practices. Like if you should only set/unset listeners and other idempotent stuff from `useEffect`. But something that increment data is not idempotent. Should I disable strict mode then?

Comment: Hm, I may need to see more code in order to play around with it as I can't think of why it would be doing it. `console.logs` and [`useWhyDidYouUpdate`](https://usehooks.com/useWhyDidYouUpdate/) is a decent hook to have in the debug process too. I would keep strict mode on as it's very helpful.  Have you considered using [ReactRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) if you're using multiple pages?